# Underscore reduce, about memo

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

According the documentation [underscore-reduce](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) I should pass three parameters.

For example:

```
var m = _.reduce([1,2,3], function (memo, num) {return (num * 2) +memo }, 0);
m; // 12 as expected
```

If I try to pass just the first two parameters I get a different value. Why?

```
var m = _.reduce([1,2,3], function (memo, num) {return (num * 2) +memo });
m; // 11 ..why?
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With only two parameters passed into [`reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce), it will use the first and second array items as arguments to the first function call.

```
function addDouble(memo, num) {return (num * 2) +memo }

[1,2,3].reduce(addDouble, 0)
// is equivalent to
addDouble(addDouble(addDouble(0, 1), 2), 3)

[1,2,3].reduce(addDouble)
// is equivalent to
addDouble(addDouble(1, 2), 3)
```

Usually you will pass the start value, but many operations have the same result when starting without their [identity element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_element). For example:

```
function add(a, b) { return a+b; }
function double(a) { return 2*a; }

[1,2,3].map(double).reduce(add) == [1,2,3].map(double).reduce(add, 0)
```

See also the docs for [native `reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 0):

If you just pass two parameters, the initial memo will take the first value of array, and the go through the rest. 11 = 1 + (2 * 2) + (3*3).  this is why.
And if you pass three parameters, the memo will take the third parameter as initial meno and go through each items of the array.